# SQL query to delete entries that contain part of string?

Tags: sql, string, command

I have a MySQL table where I want to delete all the entries that contain a part of a string -

for example, in the field "photo_name", a lot of entries might have strings like these:

```
testb-image-0.jpg
testc-image-0.jpg
testd-image-0.jpg
etc ...
```

I want to delete all entries that have the term "image-0" as part of the string in this "photo_names" field -

How do you delete entries based on a part of a string?

Answer (score 15):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE photo_name LIKE '%image-0.jpg'
```

Note that `%` stands for zero or more characters.
You can also use `_` which stands for exactly 1 character.

Comment: Just to clarify things: *ibram*'s particular example means *'match where `photo_name` **ends** with the string'*, not just *contains* it (somewhere in the middle), because there's no `%` or `_` after the fixed part of the pattern (which is `image-0.jpg`).